# Scan QrCode from windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, qr-code

Windows phone 7.5 can scan QrCodes if you use the search button.

I'd like to scan QrCodes in my own app, is there a way to call the windows phone scan functionality?
Or, if not, how can I implement one myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: see this project https://github.com/Redth/ZxingSharp.Mobile/

---

For one walk thought of how to do this, try:

http://jonas.follesoe.no/2011/07/22/qr-code-scanning-on-windows-phone-75-using-zxlib/

With source code published on:

https://github.com/follesoe/WinPhoneSamples/tree/master/ScannerDemo